# Transmog set in WoW that looks like a white space suit

Tags: world-of-warcraft

There is a caster/cloth transmog set in World of Warcraft that has some casters (I've seen a mage and warlock thus far) look like they're in a completely white space suit. It's unbelievably cool looking and I'd love to get the set for my mage and priest. The head piece looks like an astronaut helmet and everything else is totally white. I'm so sorry for sounding vague, but surely someone here who is into transmog knows what I'm talking about?

** NOTE **

I'm still trying to search for the armory link of an individual I've seen in this suit. I unfortunately don't remember their characters name. Will update this thread if I find it.

Answer (score 4):

With the many different transmog options out there, the individual pieces that the players used could be one of many. However, assuming that this is a fairly common set and focusing on the "all white" and astronaut-like look leads to a couple of possibilities. According to the list of transmog sets on [wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/transmog-sets) for caster classes (priest/warlock/mage):

[a] The set with the most astronaut-like helmet while being (mostly) white is the [Whisperwind Regalia](http://www.wowhead.com/transmog-set=1258) set.

[b] Relaxing the all-white standard (on the assumption that a player could use white items from other sets or non-sets), there are two other head pieces that could conceivably be construed for astronaut helmets: [The Cowl (or Hood) of the Cleansing Flame](http://www.wowhead.com/transmog-set=616) and [The Crown of Burning Waters](http://www.wowhead.com/transmog-set=480). (Both links are to the full transmog set for those items.

Answer (score 2):

The helmet is most likely an engineering craft. This is most likely the one you are looking for: http://www.wowhead.com/item=10588

The other helmet is more of a deep sea divers one: http://www.wowhead.com/item=10506

As far as the "All white" outfit it would be very difficult to put together, but I believe that Lin has the right option the [Whisperwind Regalia](http://www.wowhead.com/transmog-set=1258), however the [Vestments of Faith](http://www.wowhead.com/itemset=525) also appear to be all white.

Another option is that they mixed and match pieces from various priest sets to create the look they are going for. This is a link to all the priest sets that are in the game, you may find what they made by looking through here: http://www.wowhead.com/itemsets?filter=cl=9#0-2+1

Comment: Just a little fyi, if you are not an engineer with a skill level of atleast 235, you *cannot* transmog the rocket helm. Basic rule of thumb, if you can't equip it, you can't transmog it.